# Does variable assignment with var do not execute right away in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm asking this, because when I try to debug code by using safari console, I found

> my_string = 'abc'
>
> "abc"

it return the the string itself in the console right away

but with var

> var my_string = 'abc'
>
> undefined

Does this mean with var, the expression of variable assignment do not execute or evaluate right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean with var, the expression of variable assignment do not execute or evaluate right away?

No.

What the console does is, it echoes the *result* of the operation you entered.

The result of a normal assignment

```
 my_string = 'abc'
```

is `abc`. The [assignment operator returns the value that it assigned.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

The `var` keyword is a special kind of assignment. It doesn't return the assigned value (for whichever internal reason), so it's not echoed by the console.

The assignment still takes place  immediately in both cases.